# How to make my Navigation Bar Drop Down

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm wanting to know if it's possible to make my navigation bar drop down and if so how. I'm sure it's a simple add but if you can explain to me what all I need to add to it in order for it to work because when I tried to add it myself it showed the dropdown item right next to the main item. 
HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Daniel's Top Ten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav 
{
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
display:inline; 
}

#nav li a {
display:inline-block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: In the html you have supplied there is nothing to "drop down"

Answer (score 1):

There is no any lines written for making a drop down. To make a drop down create nested `ul` element. Have a look at the Demo Code here. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ramumebe/1/edit)** First.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Daniel's Top Ten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>
          <!-- Drop down Code Starts here -->
           <ul>
            <li>Registration</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
          </ul>
      <!-- Drop down Code Ends here -->
       </li>
</ul>
```

**And CSS will be**

```
#nav li ul{display:none;}
#nav li:hover ul{display:block;}
```